# Overwriting rails URL helper (form_for)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to override a url helper that is being called from a form_for.

My controllers and models are all namespaced in the "Admin" module, and are resting in an admin folder. (So models/admin/foo.rb, controllers/admin/foo_controller.rb)

My routes are correct (I believe)

```
scope module: "admin" do
    resources :foos do
      resources :foo_details
    end 
end
```

Here is some code to demonstrate what I am attempting to do and where I get the error:

```
<%= form_for(@foo) do |f| %>
```

I am getting an error on the form for line, with this: "undefined method `admin_foos_path' for #<#:0x007f08fd7ffb90>.

When I run 'rake routes', I have a route for foos, but not admin_foos.  I assume the form_for is trying to access admin_foos_path because of how the application was scaffolded.

Is there a way for me to override admin_foos_path to be foos_path or redirect it?  I have tried searching for this issue and haven't been able to come up with much.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `namespace` directive

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :foos do 
    resources :foo_details
  end
end
```

Using `scope` just gives you `foos_path`, while `namespace` gives `admin_foos_path` which is needed for the `@foo` to work.

Comment: Hey iceman, that's what i was initially using, but I was running into a problem with nested forms where if i was trying it call @admin_foo.admin_foo_details.build it would give me an error saying Admin::Foo::AdminFooDetails is undefined or uninitialized.  Others have suggested possibly dropping the admin namespace all together.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Nad97 That error  is most likely to do with how you have setup the associations in those models or somewhere you are calling a wrong classname. The error means it cant find `AdminFooDetails` for `AdminFoo`. It is nothing to do with this answer!

Answer (score 1):

> undefined method `admin_foos_path' for

To explain the error, `@foo` is a *model instance* of `Admin::Foo` not `Foo`, so `form_for` by default look for its *resourceful route* which in your case it is `admin_foos`. And because it can't find it, so is the error.

> Is there a way for me to override admin_foos_path to be foos_path or
>   redirect it?

You can overwrite the *URL* of a form to your *desired URL* like below

```
<%= form_for(@foo, url: foos_path) do |f| %>
```

But I believe you need `namespace` instead of `scope`. I recommend to read about *when to use scope and namespace* in [*controller-namespaces-and-routing*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)